# Power BI Map Dynamic Buckets

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a map visual in Power BI having a 3 level `drilldown`. State --> Station -->Meter ID.
The map essentially shows malfunctioning meters.

The below is my map table structure :

[image]

The Legend categories are '<0.1% Malfunctioning' and '>=0.1% Malfunctioning". So the Legend has to be caluclated dynamically based on drill down level and also based on the filters applied.

State,Station,Date,Billing-cycle,Meter-status,Manufacturer are user select tab filters.

Legend Table : (Legend column would go into Legend field for the map)

[image]

I'm trying to use the disconnected table approach and the summarize statement, but I'm kind of stuck on what I should be returning after summarizing. Partial `DAX` measure below:

```
MissingreadsBucket = 
var Summary = SUMMARIZE(MM_LocationData,MM_LocationData[ID],
"Bucket", 
iF(
    COUNTROWS(MM_LocationData)/CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(MM_LocationData),ALL(MM_LocationData[IsMeterMissingRead])) > 0.001,
    ">=0.1% Malfunctioning","<0.1% Malfunctioning")
```

Please Help . Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this Question myself as a work around was found.

If we are willing to let go of the ability to click on the legend , We can format the icon color of the map by using the conditional formatting option shown below.

[image]

For the legend, We will have to make do with an image or formatted table as shown below:

[image]